# Splitting the double integral

Tags: calculus

Is there any difference between

$$\int_{-\pi}^0xdx\int_0^{-\sqrt{\pi^{2}-x^2}}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/4}dy$$

and

$$\int_{-\pi}^0\int_0^{-\sqrt{\pi^{2}-x^2}}x(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/4}dydx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing your integrand as
$$
-x(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/4}\cdot1_{[0,-\sqrt{\pi^{2}-x^2}]}(y)
$$ it is a continuous function over $[-\pi,0]\times [-\pi,0]$ with the same sign over it, thus [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) applies here.